# Live migration (kvm) not working if any I/O operation is in progress

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I did this experiment: on VM I started watching a video on youtube.
While video was in progress I started migration.
Migration did not complete until video was not finished.

I did another experiment: I installed a web server on VM.
I then started an httperf stress test.
As before migration did not complete until the stress test was closed.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'd consider this to be normal (depending on what network equipment you're using).

Live migration requires that the entire contents of the VM's RAM be synchronized between hosts. If there is a high rate of change in RAM contents during the migration, synchronization may never complete, or may take a very long time.

If you're currently using 1G uplinks, you may consider upgrading to 10G NICs and a 10G switch.